# TFS grant permissions to only one Branch

Tags: security, tfs, permissions, branch

I was asked to grant permissions to several TFS users.
These users must have access to one branch only. How can I do this?

I'm going to create new TFS user group and deny access to root of Source Control, then allow access to necessary branch. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

That is the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work. Because Deny permission has higher priority than Allow even Deny even if it exist on parent. Deny permission always override Allow permissions. If you are using TFVC as source control, you could set the permission of root to "Not Set" and in then set "Allow" access to the branch you needed.
Remember that in GitVC it's a little diffrent.